# set spacing between paragraph and table in iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Look at the code and resume using itextsharp..
In which I have a paragraph with the text 'Education'.

After that I have a table which show my education details 
but to need to set gap between them..

Please see the attached picture:

My code:

[image]

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(5)
         { WidthPercentage = 100, RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_LTR, ExtendLastRow = false };


        // table.TotalWidth = doc.PageSize.Width - doc.LeftMargin - doc.RightMargin;


          table.PaddingTop = 300f;
        table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;


        table.AddCell("DEGREE");
        table.AddCell("NAME OF INSTITE");
        table.AddCell("UNVERISTY");
        table.AddCell("YEAR OF PASSING");
        table.AddCell("SCORE");

        table.AddCell(" ");
        table.AddCell(" ");
        table.AddCell( );
        table.AddCell(" ");
        table.AddCell(" ");

        table.AddCell(" ");
        table.AddCell(" c");
        table.AddCell(" ");
        table.AddCell(" ");
        table.AddCell("  %");

        table.AddCell(" ");
        table.AddCell(" ");
        table.AddCell(" d");
        table.AddCell(" ");
        table.AddCell("  %");



        doc.Add(table);
```

Comment: I usually cheat and add a blank paragraph

Comment: Unrelated to your question: it looks very bad on a resume to have spelling errors like "Instite" (Institute) or "Unveristy" (University). Also, "year of passing", is that the year somebody died? Or did you mean to write "graduation year"? Please have someone else proofread your text before you put it into production. Also, are there really places in the world where your education scores from years or decades ago matter to apply for a job?

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse thanks for suggestion... i just added the to make code title meaningful i'll check all content before last build :)

Comment: @MattBeldon i did the same but spicing was not up to to my requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well `SpacingAfter` worked for me,

just add `table.SpacingAfter = 20;`

and    `table.SpacingBefore = 20;`

worked perfectly for me

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
table.setSpacingAfter(20);
```

Comment: `setSpacingAfter(...)` is for the Java version of iText, `SpacingAfter = ...` is for the .Net version of it. And where there is `After`, there also is `Before`.